# The "only-visible-child" element?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I have a big outer **div** with many identical circles *(which is a smaller **div** with border-radius 100%)* in it.

I am using jquery to fade out these circles s when a user clicks on them, however I want to add additional event when the only remaining circle is clicked.

**:last-child** or **:nth-child()** are not going to help, as I don't mind which circle is clicked until only one of them remains.

---

Again, the elements are **FADED OUT** so they are still siblings of the visible elements. So what I need is to select the "last visible" element.

```
<div>

<div class="circle"></div>

<div class="circle"></div>

<div class="circle"></div>

<div class="circle"></div>

<div class="circle"></div>

<div class="circle"></div>

<div class="circle"></div>

<div class="circle"></div>

</div>
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".circle").click(function(){
        $(this).fadeOut("slow");
    });
    $("XXX").click(function(){
        alert("I was the last of Mohicans");
    });
});
```

Comment: show us your code... or jsfiddle may be

Comment: Why don't you show us some example source code? It would be easier to help you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not

```
.circle:first-child:last-child {
```

?

**EDIT for edited question :**

If you want to test when clicking if the element is the only one visible, you can do this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".circle").click(function(){
        $(this).fadeOut("slow");
        if ($('.circle:visible').length>1) return; // returns if not the last one
        alert("I was the last of Mohicans");
    });
});
```

Comment: Of course this works fine for selecting the only child, but my question was not correct so I edited it.

Comment: Why do you have `$(".circle").click(function()` twice? I didn't know that was possible with jQuery?

Comment: I had it because it's in OP's question. But yes it's possible and jQuery guarantees the execution order to be the insertion one.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery actually has an `only-child` selector, see here: http://api.jquery.com/only-child-selector/

(hope I've understood what you're asking properly)

**In light of edits to the question please see below:**

maybe you should try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".circle").click(function(){
        var numCircles = $('.circle').length;
        var numFaded = $('.faded').length;
        if( (numCircles - numFaded) == 1 ) {
            alert("I was the last of Mohicans!");
        }
        $(this).fadeOut("slow");
        $(this).addClass("faded");
    });
});
```

I realise the above isn't probably optimal (I'm no JavaScript/jQuery master) but it should be reasonably fast (as long as you don't add A LOT of cirlces) and it should function as you need.

Bear in mind I have not tested the above, hopefully if it doesn't work it should at least bump you in the right direction, but if you need more help please comment below.

Comment: @dystroy

Well maybe my question was not correct. Both answers provide a valid way to select the only child element, but as I'm using **fadeOut**, elements still stay in HTML file, so none of them ever becomes the only child. Sorry I didn't know this before.

I'll edit the question to avoid further confusions.

Comment: Ok I understand, I'll amend my answer

Comment: Amended my answer, hopefully that's what you're looking for!

Answer (score 1):

A work-around would be to put an extra class to those divs and with only child. When $(".extraclass :only-child") is clicked than add your new event. else remove your extraclass and apply the fade-out effect.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".circle").click(function () {
   var $this = $(this);
   $this.fadeOut("slow");
   if ($this.siblings(':visible').length === 0) {
     alert("I was the last of Mohicans");
   }
 });
});
```

Taking visible siblings count would be best option...
If you need, you can add class selector also..